# Array index out of bounds. Interface Packets dropped: String (PowerShell)

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell, system-center

Wrote a script to create incidents (objects) in bulk in SCSM (Microsoft System Center Service Manager) using PowerShell. The script pulls the data required from a CSV file. I am running into the following error:

```
New-SCSMIncident : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At C:\Users\portalservice\Desktop\scripts\Incidents\BULK_Create_Incidents.ps1:83 char:5 +     New-SCSMIncident -Title $Title -Description $Description -AffectedUser $Affe ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Interface Packets Dropped :String) [New-SCSMIncident], IndexOutOfRangeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewIncident,SMLets.SCSMIncidentNew
```

When I echo the contents of the array I see normal data... it all looks correct. Here is my script:

```
# Script designed to create tickets in bulk, reading the information needed from a CSVfile
# Tailored for incidents, can be modified to work with any work item
# SirLearnAlot 2015

# NOTES: Modify the $path variable to match the path of the data file being imported

# Import the smlets module
ipmo SMLets
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Importing Smlets..."

# ---------------------------------------- Variable Decleration ----------------------------------------
Write-Host "Getting the classes needed..."
# Get the incident class
$IncidentClass = Get-SCSMClass -Name System.WorkItem.Incident$
# Get the CI Class
$CIClass = Get-SCSMClass -Name COMPANY.CI.Class$
# Get the Relationship we want to add (Affected Items)
$RelWIaboutCI = Get-SCSMRelationshipClass -Name System.WorkItemAboutConfigItem$
# Clear the error variable incase it contains anything already
$error.clear()

# --------------------------------------------- Data Import --------------------------------------------
# Import the CSV Data file containing list of incidents to create and their information
Write-Host "Importing CSV Data File..."
$path = "C:\Users\portalservice\Desktop\Script Data\Work Item Creation\Incidents\11.12.15\data.csv"
$data = ipcsv $path
if ($error -like "Could not find file *")
{
    Write-Host "Encountered an error while importing the data file from '$path'. Please verify the path directories and file exist and run the script again."
    exit
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Successfully imported data file!"
    Write-Host "Beginning ticket creation..."
    #pause
}
# ---------------------------------------------- Execution ---------------------------------------------
# Begin going through file line by line
foreach ($case in $data)
{
    # Clear the error variable
    $error.clear()

# Visual Formatting
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
Write-Host ""

# GETTING THE INFORMATION FROM DATA FILE AND STORING IN VARIABLES
# Get the Info for the Incident to create
$Title = $case.Title
Write-Host "Got case title: $Title"
$Description = $case.Description
Write-Host "Got case description: $Description"
$AffectedUser = $case.AffectedUser
Write-Host "Got case affected user: $AffectedUser"
$Classification = $case.Classification
Write-Host "Got case classification: $Classification"
$Impact = $case.Impact
Write-Host "Got case impact: $Impact"
$Urgency = $case.Urgency
Write-Host "Got case urgency: $Urgency"
$SupportGroup = $case.SupportGroup
Write-Host "Got case support group: $SupportGroup"
$PrimaryOwner = $case.PrimaryOwner
Write-Host "Got case owner: $PrimaryOwner"
$Vendor = $case.Vendor
Write-Host "Got case vendor: $Vendor"
$Customer = $case.Customer
Write-Host "Got case customer: $Customer"
$ReportedOn = $case.ReportedOn
Write-Host "Got date reported on: $ReportedOn"
# Get the name of the correct CI to add
$CIToAddNum = $case.CI
Write-Host "Got case CI: $CIToAddNum"
# Apply the non-OOB Values to the property hash table
$PropertyHashTable = @{"Vendor" = $Vendor; "Customer" = $Customer; "Reported_On" = $ReportedOn}

# INCIDENT CREATION
Write-Host "Attemping to create Incident from case data..."
New-SCSMIncident -Title $Title -Description $Description -AffectedUser $AffectedUser -Classification $Classification -Impact $Impact -Urgency $Urgency -SupportGroup $SupportGroup -Bulk
# Checks to see if the there is an error, if so displays a warning message and exits
if (!$error)
{
    Write-Host "Incident creation successful."
}
else
{
    Write-Host "$error"
    Write-Host "Error creating the incident. Check the incident creation code and run this script again."
    exit
}

# INCIDENT RETRIEVAL (POST-CREATION)
Write-Host "Attempting to retrieve incident for modification (Adding Customer, Vendor, and Reported On date to ticket)"
$Incident = Get-SCSMObject -Class $IncidentClass -Filter "Description -like '%$Description%'"
# Checks to see if the retrieval failed, if so displays error message and exits script
if ($Incident = $null)
{
    Write-Host "Incident retrieval failed. Check the incident retrieval code and run the script again."
    exit
}
# Apply the property hash table to the retrieved incident  
$Incident | Set-SCSMObject -PropertyHashtable $PropertyHashTable

# ADDING THE CI TO THE INCIDENT
# Get the CI from the CMDB
$CIToAdd = Get-SCSMObject -Class $CIClass -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$CIToAddNum'"
if ($CIToAdd = $null)
{   
    Write-Host "Cannot find $CIToAddNum in the database, this CI does not seem to exist or the code to retrieve the CI failed. Please import the CI into the SMDB or fix the retrieval code and run this script again"
    exit
}
# Attempt to add the CI to the Incident (Create a new relationship)
# Note: Due to a bug the -bulk paramater is required 
Write-Host "Attempting to add $CIToAddNum to Incident..."
New-SCSMRelationshipObject -Relationship $RelWIaboutCI -Source $Incident -Target $CIToAdd -bulk
# Check if script throws error (cannot find the CI from the data file in our SMDB)
# If so provides error message and exits, otherwise provides success message
    if ($error -like "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Target' because it is null.")
    {
        Write-Host "Encountered an error while trying to add $CIToAddNum to $IncidentNum, this CI is not in the Service Manager Database or there was a problem retrieving it. Please import the CI into the SMDB or check the retrieval code and run this script again"
        exit
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Successfully Added!"
    }
}
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Success! All Incidents Corrected :)"
```

Not sure what the problem is here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hit this same problem, my solution was to instead use New-SCSMObject.
Here is a simple example:

```
    $irprops = @{Title = 'test'
                 Description = 'test descripton'
                 Impact = (get-scsmenumeration -name 'System.WorkItem.TroubleTicket.ImpactEnum.Low')
                 Urgency = (get-scsmenumeration -name 'System.WorkItem.TroubleTicket.UrgencyEnum.Medium')
                 ID = "IR{0}"
                 Status = (get-scsmenumeration -name 'System.WorkItem.TroubleTicket.ImpactEnum.Low')
                 Priority = 2
     }

     $ir=new-scsmobject -Class (get-scsmclass -name 'System.WorkItem.Incident$') -PropertyHashtable $irprops -PassThru
```